# Trying to correct a program, can't even get it to run

Tags: java, class, netbeans, program-entry-point

I'm using Netbeans, and trying to get a program "Rational" to run, so that I can see what needs to be fixed. However, when I try to run it, I get the error "Rational.Main class wasn't found in Rational project". I've tried renaming several aspects of the program to make it see the main class (it is there, I assure you), but it still gives this error. I've seen it before, but this is the only time it hasn't seemed to fix itself in time.

Edit: This is more problematic than I thought, here's the updated code. Yes, it's very wrong.

```
 package Rational;

  public class Rational {
        int x, y;



       public Rational () {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    public static void printRational (Rational x) {
        System.out.println (x);
    }
    public Rational (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public static void negate (int x) {
        x = -x;
        System.out.println (x);
    }
    public static void invert (int x, int y) {
        int g = x;
        x = y;
        y = g;
        System.out.print (x);
        System.out.print ("/");
        System.out.println (y);
    }
    public static void toDouble (int x, int y) {
        double f = x/y;
        System.out.println (f);
    }
    public static int GCD(int a, int b)
{
   if (b==0) return a;
   return GCD(b,a%b);
}
    public static void reduce (int x, int y) {
        x = x/(GCD (x,y));
        y = y/(GCD (x,y));
        System.out.print (x);
        System.out.print ("/");
        System.out.println (y);
    }
    public static void add (int x, int y) {
        double z = x+y;
        System.out.println (z);
    }






public static void main(String args[]) {
     Rational g = new Rational ();{
g.x = 1;
g.y = 2;
System.out.println ("vgds");
//Rational.printRational (g);

      }
}
}
```

Updated screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX55P.png]

Comment: Do you have a `public class Main` in Main.java?

Comment: Can you post the source code that contains your `Rational.Main` class? (You can redact anything except for the class and main method headings)

Comment: Have you compiled the project before running? Since the Main class seems to exist it might just be the .class file that is missing (or it is not on the classpath).

Comment: Bala: I do not, but I'm not sure where that would go.


Jen: I'll post it in a moment, sure.


Thomas: I just compiled it, chose the only available main class, and  then ran, and now it seems to only display three infinite lines of squares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class name is Rational but your file name is Main.java

**Just make them same your problem will be solved.**

For any public class in java the filename and the class name should be same and also,
a file can contain only one public class.

Comment: This sounds simple. I just tried renaming the class name and got errors in the code, is there a way to rename the file name?

Comment: when renaming you have to replace the previous name everywhere you used with the new one. Better is to use Find/Replace tool of the editor.

Comment: Check it your Rational.java file is under Rational folder. Cause you used "package Rational". So the file structure should be something like   [your_working_directory]/src/Rational/Rational.java

Comment: If it is in the correct folder but still the error is appearing..then upload the updated screen shot and whole code

Comment: Alright, it's running, but only displaying infinite (in theory) lines of squares. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the file name problem the previous answer alludes to, you also need to make the class Rational public, and you're probably going to have problems if you make the package name the same as the class name.

The filename should be Rational.java

The signature should be:

public class Rational

The package name should not also be Rational.  You can use lower case 'rational' if you like.

Answer (score 0):

May be you wanted something like this:

```
package Rational;

public class Rational {
int x, y;

public Rational() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

public static void print(Rational r)
{       
    System.out.println("" + (r.x + r.y));
}

// other stuff

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Rational g = new Rational();
    g.x = 1;
    g.y = 2;

    Rational.print(g);


}
}
```